# React Native expo-image cacheKey Functionality

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use the [expo-image](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/image) package with pre-signed S3 images. However, the images are taking several seconds to load even if I've already loaded them before. Due to the dynamic nature of the pre-signed S3 URL, I'm truncating the image at the first '?' to create the cacheKey, which should create a static key per object.

Am I using the cacheKey correctly? Given how long it's taking to display the images, it seems as though the images aren't being cached. However, when I print out the onLoad events, I can see "cacheType": "disk".

```
import { Image } from 'expo-image'
let uri = 'https://abcdefghi.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/152/message/myImageHere?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%2F20231115%2Fap-southeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231115T143523Z&X-Amz-Expires=432000&X-Amz-Signature=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-id=GetObject'
<Image source={{ uri, cacheKey: uri.split('?')[0] }} />
```